# Aml Workspace ID in Azure Databricks Service

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to know if the AML workspace ID needs to be configured at initial creation of a Databricks workspace or it can be taken as an update thereafter without destroying the workspace[image]

Answer (score 1):

No it's not required at creation time - link to Azure ML could be added after workspace is created. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-mlflow-azure-databricks?tabs=azuremlsdk#dual-tracking-on-azure-databricks-and-azure-machine-learning) for steps.